# Getting the mat-icon-button to render in the right place when using mat-menu-item?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

When we associate a `button mat-icon-button` with a `mat-menu` the button moves over further to the left.

How do we get it to render in the same place that it would if it were not associated with a `mat-menu`.

[This is a demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-mat-toolbar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

If we comment out:

```
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Guides</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Concepts</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Tasks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Formulas</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

And replace it with:

```
    <button mat-icon-button>
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

We can see where the button renders without the associated `mat-menu`.

Answer (score 0):

Just flip the order of the elements:

```
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Guides</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Concepts</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Tasks</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Formulas</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
```